# Debugging DSP Application Remotly With GDB and QT Creator

Tags: debugging, gdb, davinci

I have an image processing application which uses QT and TI Video Decoder example, it runs on TI DaVinci, DM6446.

I am using QT Creator and compile process gives me two binaries, one for the ARM core, one for the DSP. The DSP binary has the extension of ".x64p".

There is no problem if i start the app directly from the target board.But if I start it using gdb on the host, i can see the debug messages on the arm side, however, it crashes immediately, because it is not able to open DSP binary.

Is there any way to debug ARM+DSP application without using TI CCS or a JTAG device ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok i can see that you have 3 "apps" here

1. Main app for the arm side
2. The codec
3. The server for the dsp side

if i am right you can use Linux Os (if you have the virtual machine known as child and parent has ubuntu which you can find at ti website)
so run this vm and

1. Build the codec (make all command)
2. Build the server (make build_server command)
3. Build the app (make all command)

hope this help

but I wanna ask you how can I make this using ccs, I can build a separate project for the dsp or arm but I wanna build the whole system..

help me if you can
...Regards